# Scan through sliding window looking for certain combination of letters in a string. Count occurrences . Python

Tags: python, string, count, window

If you have a sequence and you create a a list of window size 4.  In each of those windows your looking for particular arrangement.

```
#Example:
count=0
test='abcdaecdagcd'
windows=['abcd','bcda','cdae','daec','aecd','ecda','cdag','dagc','agcd']
```

I'm looking for a particular motif which is a-[b or e]-*-d within the sequence and I want to count how many times it occurs

so 'abcd' and 'aecd' would work because 'a-[b or e]-(this position doesn't matter)-d' which would add to the count 2 so after the function went through it would be count = 2

Comment: Looks like a regular expression may help.

Answer (score 1):

A string 'a(b or e)*d' can't begin in a string 'a(b or e)*d'. Hence strings of this kind present in a long string can't overlap, and then a regex is usable to find what you need:

```
import re

ss = 'abcdaecdagcd'

regx = re.compile('a[be].d')

print regx.findall(ss)
print len(regx.findall(ss))
```

result

```
['abcd', 'aecd']
2
```